# Is it possible to use D-noise from a picture?

Tags: rendering, add-on

As far as I know we can use [D-noise](https://remingtongraphics.net/tools/d-noise/) tool just after rendering. I wonder if we can use it loading an already rendered image instead.

Comment: You can also add image as plane, setup your camera, render with D-Noise enabled. No need to answer that question then

Answer (score 1):

As we can clearly see on https://remingtongraphics.net/tools/d-noise/ after entering "d-noise" on pretty much any search engine and clicking the first result it says:

> ## Denoise Anything
>
> D-NOISE isn’t exclusive to renders like the Cycles denoiser is.
> D-NOISE can run on any image loaded into the UV/Image Editor including
> texture bakes and even photos!

And here is a screenshot of that:

[image]

Comment: Does it say how?

Comment: I already read that and tried to load the image, but it didn't work, tried 2.8 and 2.79 in Windows 10 64 bits

On the other side, I've just installed a new GTX 650 ti with latests drivers and D-noise didn't work at all.

Comment: Did you follow the installation instructions and downloaded the Optix Libraries? It might just be that it works poorly on some particular image as well.

Comment: I'll check. My picture in fact has a lot of dust-like particles that may confuse the AI and can't say what is noise and what is the particle system.
I didn't know about Optix library, I thought it was just an addon process as a regular one.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's kind of obvious once you enable it.

Here is the UV editor.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [this tool](https://declanrussell.com/portfolio/nvidia-ai-denoiser/) instead.

Comment: It looks very similar, thanks. I'll check when I get my hands in my computer with NVIDIA